# Rails dynamic attribute in where LIKE clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a search method, which takes in a key value pair in argument and searches on an active record model via a LIKE query. But I am unable to get it to work. It doesn't take the key argument properly.

This is what my method looks like:

```
def search(key,value)
  where('? LIKE ?',key,"%#{value}%")
end
```

The query it fires is `('name' LIKE '%air%')` whereas it should fire `(name LIKE '%air%')`

Is there a way I could get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warning: The solution proposed by @MKumar is very dangerous. If `key` is user-input, you just allowed SQL injection.

```rb
def search(key, value)
  where("#{key} LIKE ?", "%#{value}%")
end
search("IS_ADMIN == 1 --", "")
```

Whoops!

The better way to do this would be to use Arel tables.

```rb
def search(key, value)
  column = Model.arel_table[key.to_sym] # index into the columns, via a symbol
  where(column.matches("%#{value}%"))
end
```

This cannot produce a SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
def search(key,value)
  where("#{key} LIKE ?","%#{value}%")
end
```

Comment: Not secure! See @ven's answer.